# Web Scrape - Span Price issue. Printing the last items price in loop instead of price for each item

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm almost happy with this script I've been putting together today.  Its came with some help today (thanks everyone who has assisted thus far) and some suspect programming on my part but it is functional to a degree.

I want to dump the data to a JSON.  It seems dump all the data correctly **apart from the price** (which was grabbed from `<span></span>`).  I believe the issue lies with indenting but I'm not 100% sure.

Could someone cast their eye over this snippet and correct what I cannot see.  Think I'm going blind with being unable to see the correct change with the amount of variations I've tried.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import shutil
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import urllib.request as urllib2
import locale
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml.html
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

#selenium requests
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html")
time.sleep(2)

#beautiful soup requests
#URL = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html'
#page = requests.get(URL)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="lxml")
#products = soup.find_all("div", "GC62 Product")
products = soup.find_all("div", "GC62 Product")

for product in products:
    #barrel lengths
    barrels = product.find('select', attrs={'name': re.compile('length')})
    if barrels:
        barrels_list = [x['origvalue'][:2] for x in barrels.find_all('option')[1:]]

        for y in range(0, len(barrels_list)):
            #title
            title = product.find("h3") 
            titleText = title.text if title else ''

            #manufacturer name
            manufacturer = product.find("div", "GC5 ProductManufacturer")
            manuText = manufacturer.text if manufacturer else ''

            #image location
            img = product.find("div", "ProductImage")
            imglinks = img.find("a") if img else ''
            imglinkhref = imglinks.get('href')  if imglinks else ''
            imgurl = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents'+imglinkhref
 
            #description
            description = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDescription")
            descText = description.text if description else ''
            #descStr = str(descText)

            #more description
            more = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDetailedDescription")
            moreText = more.text if more else ''

            #price
            spans = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.GC20.ProductPrice span")
            for i in range(0,len(spans),2):
                span = spans[i].text
                i+=1 
                
                #print(span)
                #print(barrels_list[y])
                #print(titleText)
                #print(manuText)
                #print(descText)
                #print(moreText)
                #print(imgurl.replace('..', ''))
                #print("\n")

            x = {
                "price": span,
                "barrel length": barrels_list[y],
                "title": titleText,
                "manufacturer": manuText,
                "description": descText,
                "desc cont": moreText,
                "image Location": imgurl.replace('..', '')
            }

            dump = json.dumps(x)
            print(dump)
            y+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded to make it work by modifying a little bit your code. Your last `for` loop is not really useful as you already found the tag of the product. Thus, you can do as follow :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import shutil
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import urllib.request as urllib2
import locale
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml.html
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

#selenium requests
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html")
time.sleep(2)

#beautiful soup requests
#URL = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html'
#page = requests.get(URL)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="lxml")
#products = soup.find_all("div", "GC62 Product")
products = soup.find_all("div", "GC62 Product")




for product in products:
    
    #barrel lengths
    barrels = product.find('select', attrs={'name': re.compile('length')})
    if barrels:
        barrels_list = [x['origvalue'][:2] for x in barrels.find_all('option')[1:]]
        
        #title
        title = product.find("h3") 
        titleText = title.text if title else ''

        #manufacturer name
        manufacturer = product.find("div", "GC5 ProductManufacturer")
        manuText = manufacturer.text if manufacturer else ''

        #image location
        img = product.find("div", "ProductImage")
        imglinks = img.find("a") if img else ''
        imglinkhref = imglinks.get('href')  if imglinks else ''
        imgurl = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents' + imglinkhref

        #description
        description = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDescription")
        descText = description.text if description else ''

        #more description
        more = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDetailedDescription")
        moreText = more.text if more else ''

        #price
        price = product.findChild(name="span")
        print("price : ", price)
        price_raw = price.text
        print("price_raw : ", price_raw)
        price_replaced = price_raw.replace(',', '').replace('£', '')
        print("price_replaced : ", price_replaced)
        price_float = float(price_replaced)

        for barrel in barrels_list:
            x = {
                "price": price_float,
                "barrel length": barrel,
                "title": titleText,
                "manufacturer": manuText,
                "description": descText,
                "desc cont": moreText,
                "image Location": imgurl.replace('..', '')
            }
            dump = json.dumps(x)
            print(dump)
```

Do not hesitate if it still does not work!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the snippet.  Im assuming you have removed from "spans = browser....." and added the above?  If so I'm getting the error:     price_float = float(next(price.children).strip().replace(',', '.'))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable ??

Comment: Mmmh it works on my side! I tried to simplify the code, can you try copy/paste to see if it works? By the way, when using a `for` instruction, no need to add `x += 1` at the end, the `for` instruction increments it by itself!

Comment: With a straight Copy and Paste from above I get the same error  - also re the for tip - thanks, genuinely didnt know that!  error: File "C:\Users\admin\mcavoy1.py", line 66, in <module>
    price_float = float(price_raw.strip().replace(',', '.'))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Okay, let's debug it, can you give me what is printed in your screen for all the `price_...` (See my code with the new `print()` lines 65, 67, 69 and 71)

Comment: from my side it seems to be the price_raw = next(price.children) when i print it i get the following as an output "<span class="ProductCurrencySymbol" sf:object="ProductCurrencySymbol">£</span>"

Comment: Interesting, let's try something a little bit different, try the nex code :)

Comment: price = product.findChild(name="span").text - not including anything else, is printing my side the correct output

Comment: File "C:\Users\admin\mcavoy1.py", line 81, in <module>
    price_float = float(price_replaced)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '£1.695.00'

Comment: I've edited your to show what is working on my side from your code. i dont know what to think of that? lol

Comment: Ahhhh, I see what happens, on my screen, the `£` sign is behind the amount. I wanted to convert the amount into a float but maybe you don't need it?

Comment: It would be useful now that you mention it.

Comment: the £ is throwing unusual text within the json i could do without

Comment: See edited code to cast to float. If it does not work, can you just give me the print value of `price.text` and I'll make it work?

Comment: i was just about to edit your  "price": price > "price": price_float but see you spotted it.  Thats it working now.  Thanks you!  stuff can be a melt sometimes - thats an interesting way for you to get the span - the amount of time i spent trying to get that information would frighten you! think i spent a whole day trying to put together my original span grab - trial error trial error losing the will to live! python/coding in general isnt a strong suit of mine, but i like to learn various things and try them for myself

Comment: there is still quite a bit of maturing to go to get it completed.  Ideally im trying to send to json: All options from the dropdown menus (barrel length, caliber, model) and all the radio buttons, then try to figure out how im going to get all images for each.  Its a very poorly constructed website as far as consistencies go so the scrap is messy!  good learning though.  like your loop for the JSON at the end was something i wasn't going to figure out, and when i saw it it made perfect sense